# How to copy from Debain (virtual machine) to host machine

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, gitlab, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to connect my VM to GitLab, and to do so I need to copy my public key to GitLab.

> cat id_rsa.pub

The problem is that I can't do that using Debian terminal. I tried

> cat id_rsa.pub | xclip

but it doesn't work and gives me the error "Error: can't open display: (null)".

How can I copy the output text to the host machine?

Comment: you might ssh from your computer into the VM and copy paste from the terminal. you could use a scp to download the file.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the the VM ip address is ipv6, the output of `ip address` command is:
`link/ether 08:00:27:8d:c0:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:c04d/64 scope link
 valid_lft forever prefferred_lft forever`

Comment: And when I try to put `fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:c04d` into PuTTY, it gives me the error "Network error: Connection timed out". I'm new to this, sorry.